# Why does Tk().after only execute once and how to fix it?

Tags: python, tkinter

Why does Tk().after only execute once and how to fix it?

I tried to rerun `.after()` within `tick()`, but if I uncomment the line, the windows os not shown at all.

Using Windows 8.1 and Python 3

```
import tkinter as tk


def tick():
    matrix_size = board.get_matrix_size()
    alive_neighbours = [[None] * matrix_size for i in range(matrix_size)]

    for row in range(matrix_size):
        for col in range(matrix_size):
            alive_neighbours[row][col] = get_alive_neighbours(row, col)

    for row in range(matrix_size):
        for col in range(matrix_size):
            if alive_neighbours[row][col] == 3:
                board.create_cell(row, col)
            elif alive_neighbours[row][col] < 2:
                board.kill_cell(row, col)
            elif alive_neighbours[row][col] == 2 and board.get_cell_state(row, col) == "alive":
                continue
            elif alive_neighbours[row][col] > 3:
                board.kill_cell(row, col)

    # root.after(1000, tick())


def get_alive_neighbours(row, col):
    alive_neighbour_count = 0

    for relative_row in range(-1, 2):  # Top cells
        for relative_col in range(-1, 2):
            if relative_row == 0 and relative_col == 0:
                continue  # Do not current cell as neighbour
            else:
                cell_state = board.get_cell_state(row + relative_row, col + relative_col)

                if cell_state == "alive":
                    alive_neighbour_count += 1

    return alive_neighbour_count


class GameBoard(tk.Frame):
    matrix_size = 10
    grid_size = 32
    matrix = []
    alive_color = "white"
    dead_color = "grey"

    def __init__(self, master=None):
        self.matrix = [[None] * self.matrix_size for i in range(self.matrix_size)]
        canvas_width = self.matrix_size * self.grid_size
        canvas_height = self.matrix_size * self.grid_size

        tk.Frame.__init__(self, master)
        self.canvas = tk.Canvas(self, width=canvas_width, height=canvas_height)
        self.draw_board()
        self.initialize_cells()
        self.canvas.grid()

    def draw_board(self):
        color = "white"
        for row in range(len(self.matrix)):
            for col in range(len(self.matrix[row])):
                # color = "white" if (col+row)%2==0 else "lightgrey"
                color = "lightgrey"
                x0 = (col * self.grid_size + 2)  # Why +2?
                y0 = (row * self.grid_size + 2)  # Why +2
                x1 = x0 + self.grid_size
                y1 = y0 + self.grid_size
                id = self.canvas.create_rectangle(x0, y0, x1, y1, fill=color, width=0)
                self.matrix[row][col] = id

    def create_cell(self, row, column):
        grid_item = self.matrix[row][column]
        self.canvas.itemconfigure(grid_item, fill=self.alive_color)

    def kill_cell(self, row, column):
        grid_item = self.matrix[row][column]
        self.canvas.itemconfigure(grid_item, fill=self.dead_color)

    def get_cell_state(self, row, column):
        try:
            grid_item = self.matrix[row][column]
        except IndexError:
            return "dead"
        else:
            fill_color = self.canvas.itemcget(grid_item, "fill")
            if fill_color == "white":
                return "alive"
            else:
                return "dead"

    def get_matrix(self):
        return self.matrix

    def get_matrix_size(self):
        return self.matrix_size

    def initialize_cells(self):
        self.create_cell(1, 1)
        self.create_cell(1, 2)
        self.create_cell(2, 1)
        self.grid()


if __name__ == "__main__":
    root = tk.Tk()
    root.resizable(0, 0)
    board = GameBoard(master=root)
    root.after(1000, tick())
    root.mainloop()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you're *calling* the methods when using them as a parameter, thus using the return value of the `tick` function (`None`).
Uncomment the line you mentioned and replace your `after` calls with

```
root.after(1000, tick)
```

Therefore, you're passing the `tick` function itself.